# Javascript Regex to match URL but not a filename

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am currently using this regex:

```
str.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
```

To check if a string is a URL in my application. I check this so I can render the URL in `<a>` tags. But in some situations, the user's string will be a filename that I *don't* want to be converted into a URL.

Does anyone have a regex pattern that would give me the the following result?

```
isUrl(www.google.com) // true
isUrl(google.com) // true
isUrl(http://google.com) // true
isUrl(https://google.com) // true
isUrl(1235_myfile.wav) // false
```

I've searched on StackO and can't find any questions that match this specific case. Thanks

Comment: You can use anchors and perhaps check for not `.wav` like `^(?:https?:\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.(?!wav\b)[a-z]{2,6}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&/=]*$` See https://regex101.com/r/OTFCIt/1

Comment: Can the file include a path? If you want to ignore "files" then you need to add the possible extensions to an ignore list.

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution worked for me in this instance - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is exclude matching `.wav` before matching `[a-z]{2,6}` using a negative lookahead `\.(?!wav\b)[a-z]{2,6}\b`

You can omit `(www\.)?` as the following character class `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}` also matches a dot and can also match a `w`

**Note** that due to the character class `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}` the pattern could also match for example `...aa`

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.(?!wav\b)[a-z]{2,6}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&/=]*$
```

Without the capture groups, the pattern could be:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTFCIt/1)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be easily done with a simple regex. You could combine an ignore list with a check for a protocol prefix, prior to evaluating the string value as a URL by passing it to the constructor.

```js
const fileExtensionIgnoreList = [ 'wav' ];

const isUrl = (url) => {
  const [ match, fileExtension ] = url.match(/\.(\w+)$/);
  if (fileExtensionIgnoreList.includes(fileExtension)) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    new URL(/^\w+:\/\//.test(url) ? url : `http://${url}`);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(isUrl('www.google.com'));     // true
console.log(isUrl('google.com'));         // true
console.log(isUrl('http://google.com'));  // true
console.log(isUrl('https://google.com')); // true
console.log(isUrl('1235_myfile.wav'));    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, there are two ways to do this.

Either include only valid top-level domains, or exclude known file extensions.

The TLD way is more comprehensive since IANA publishes and updates a list [here](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt), while file extensions can be anything.

The regex should look like this (replace `list|of|tlds` by the list separated with the `|` delimiter):

```
((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?([\w_\.-]+(?:\.(list|of|tlds\b))([\w.,?^=%&@:/~+#-]*[\w?^=%&@/~+#-])?
```

Explanation:

- `((http|ftp|https)\:\/\/)?` the string http/ftp/https may or may not exist at the beginning
- `([\w_\.-]+` at least one or more words, separated by dashes or dots
- `(?:\.(list|of|tlds\b))` confirm the existence of a TLD after a dot
- `([\w.,?^=%&@:/~+#-]*[\w?^=%&@/~+#-])?` checks for all other strings that can exist after the TLD (query parameters, page sections etc.) that contain the mentioned special characters and words, any number of times.

You can see an example regex in https://regex101.com/r/UmTGlO/2.

As you can see, it detects urls but not any other string.

Note that since we explicitly look for the existence of a TLD, this regex will not match any IP addresses (that, depending on your problem, do or do not classify as urls).

Answer (score 0):

for valid domain check (isUrl?) (may be memory leak) i got list from https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

```
(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.(AAA|AARP|ABARTH|ABB|ABBOTT|ABBVIE|ABC|ABLE|ABOGADO|ABUDHABI|AC|ACADEMY|ACCENTURE|ACCOUNTANT|ACCOUNTANTS|ACO|ACTOR|AD|ADAC|ADS|ADULT|AE|AEG|AERO|AETNA|AF|AFAMILYCOMPANY|AFL|AFRICA|AG|AGAKHAN|AGENCY|AI|AIG|AIRBUS|AIRFORCE|AIRTEL|AKDN|AL|ALFAROMEO|ALIBABA|ALIPAY|ALLFINANZ|ALLSTATE|ALLY|ALSACE|ALSTOM|AM|AMAZON|AMERICANEXPRESS|AMERICANFAMILY|AMEX|AMFAM|AMICA|AMSTERDAM|ANALYTICS|ANDROID|ANQUAN|ANZ|AO|AOL|APARTMENTS|APP|APPLE|AQ|AQUARELLE|AR|ARAB|ARAMCO|ARCHI|ARMY|ARPA|ART|ARTE|AS|ASDA|ASIA|ASSOCIATES|AT|ATHLETA|ATTORNEY|AU|AUCTION|AUDI|AUDIBLE|AUDIO|AUSPOST|AUTHOR|AUTO|AUTOS|AVIANCA|AW|AWS|AX|AXA|AZ|AZURE|BA|BABY|BAIDU|BANAMEX|BANANAREPUBLIC|BAND|BANK|BAR|BARCELONA|BARCLAYCARD|BARCLAYS|BAREFOOT|BARGAINS|BASEBALL|BASKETBALL|BAUHAUS|BAYERN|BB|BBC|BBT|BBVA|BCG|BCN|BD|BE|BEATS|BEAUTY|BEER|BENTLEY|BERLIN|BEST|BESTBUY|BET|BF|BG|BH|BHARTI|BI|BIBLE|BID|BIKE|BING|BINGO|BIO|BIZ|BJ|BLACK|BLACKFRIDAY|BLOCKBUSTER|BLOG|BLOOMBERG|BLUE|BM|BMS|BMW|BN|BNPPARIBAS|BO|BOATS|BOEHRINGER|BOFA|BOM|BOND|BOO|BOOK|BOOKING|BOSCH|BOSTIK|BOSTON|BOT|BOUTIQUE|BOX|BR|BRADESCO|BRIDGESTONE|BROADWAY|BROKER|BROTHER|BRUSSELS|BS|BT|BUDAPEST|BUGATTI|BUILD|BUILDERS|BUSINESS|BUY|BUZZ|BV|BW|BY|BZ|BZH|CA|CAB|CAFE|CAL|CALL|CALVINKLEIN|CAM|CAMERA|CAMP|CANCERRESEARCH|CANON|CAPETOWN|CAPITAL|CAPITALONE|CAR|CARAVAN|CARDS|CARE|CAREER|CAREERS|CARS|CASA|CASE|CASH|CASINO|CAT|CATERING|CATHOLIC|CBA|CBN|CBRE|CBS|CC|CD|CENTER|CEO|CERN|CF|CFA|CFD|CG|CH|CHANEL|CHANNEL|CHARITY|CHASE|CHAT|CHEAP|CHINTAI|CHRISTMAS|CHROME|CHURCH|CI|CIPRIANI|CIRCLE|CISCO|CITADEL|CITI|CITIC|CITY|CITYEATS|CK|CL|CLAIMS|CLEANING|CLICK|CLINIC|CLINIQUE|CLOTHING|CLOUD|CLUB|CLUBMED|CM|CN|CO|COACH|CODES|COFFEE|COLLEGE|COLOGNE|COM|COMCAST|COMMBANK|COMMUNITY|COMPANY|COMPARE|COMPUTER|COMSEC|CONDOS|CONSTRUCTION|CONSULTING|CONTACT|CONTRACTORS|COOKING|COOKINGCHANNEL|COOL|COOP|CORSICA|COUNTRY|COUPON|COUPONS|COURSES|CPA|CR|CREDIT|CREDITCARD|CREDITUNION|CRICKET|CROWN|CRS|CRUISE|CRUISES|CSC|CU|CUISINELLA|CV|CW|CX|CY|CYMRU|CYOU|CZ|DABUR|DAD|DANCE|DATA|DATE|DATING|DATSUN|DAY|DCLK|DDS|DE|DEAL|DEALER|DEALS|DEGREE|DELIVERY|DELL|DELOITTE|DELTA|DEMOCRAT|DENTAL|DENTIST|DESI|DESIGN|DEV|DHL|DIAMONDS|DIET|DIGITAL|DIRECT|DIRECTORY|DISCOUNT|DISCOVER|DISH|DIY|DJ|DK|DM|DNP|DO|DOCS|DOCTOR|DOG|DOMAINS|DOT|DOWNLOAD|DRIVE|DTV|DUBAI|DUCK|DUNLOP|DUPONT|DURBAN|DVAG|DVR|DZ|EARTH|EAT|EC|ECO|EDEKA|EDU|EDUCATION|EE|EG|EMAIL|EMERCK|ENERGY|ENGINEER|ENGINEERING|ENTERPRISES|EPSON|EQUIPMENT|ER|ERICSSON|ERNI|ES|ESQ|ESTATE|ET|ETISALAT|EU|EUROVISION|EUS|EVENTS|EXCHANGE|EXPERT|EXPOSED|EXPRESS|EXTRASPACE|FAGE|FAIL|FAIRWINDS|FAITH|FAMILY|FAN|FANS|FARM|FARMERS|FASHION|FAST|FEDEX|FEEDBACK|FERRARI|FERRERO|FI|FIAT|FIDELITY|FIDO|FILM|FINAL|FINANCE|FINANCIAL|FIRE|FIRESTONE|FIRMDALE|FISH|FISHING|FIT|FITNESS|FJ|FK|FLICKR|FLIGHTS|FLIR|FLORIST|FLOWERS|FLY|FM|FO|FOO|FOOD|FOODNETWORK|FOOTBALL|FORD|FOREX|FORSALE|FORUM|FOUNDATION|FOX|FR|FREE|FRESENIUS|FRL|FROGANS|FRONTDOOR|FRONTIER|FTR|FUJITSU|FUN|FUND|FURNITURE|FUTBOL|FYI|GA|GAL|GALLERY|GALLO|GALLUP|GAME|GAMES|GAP|GARDEN|GAY|GB|GBIZ|GD|GDN|GE|GEA|GENT|GENTING|GEORGE|GF|GG|GGEE|GH|GI|GIFT|GIFTS|GIVES|GIVING|GL|GLADE|GLASS|GLE|GLOBAL|GLOBO|GM|GMAIL|GMBH|GMO|GMX|GN|GODADDY|GOLD|GOLDPOINT|GOLF|GOO|GOODYEAR|GOOG|GOOGLE|GOP|GOT|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GRAINGER|GRAPHICS|GRATIS|GREEN|GRIPE|GROCERY|GROUP|GS|GT|GU|GUARDIAN|GUCCI|GUGE|GUIDE|GUITARS|GURU|GW|GY|HAIR|HAMBURG|HANGOUT|HAUS|HBO|HDFC|HDFCBANK|HEALTH|HEALTHCARE|HELP|HELSINKI|HERE|HERMES|HGTV|HIPHOP|HISAMITSU|HITACHI|HIV|HK|HKT|HM|HN|HOCKEY|HOLDINGS|HOLIDAY|HOMEDEPOT|HOMEGOODS|HOMES|HOMESENSE|HONDA|HORSE|HOSPITAL|HOST|HOSTING|HOT|HOTELES|HOTELS|HOTMAIL|HOUSE|HOW|HR|HSBC|HT|HU|HUGHES|HYATT|HYUNDAI|IBM|ICBC|ICE|ICU|ID|IE|IEEE|IFM|IKANO|IL|IM|IMAMAT|IMDB|IMMO|IMMOBILIEN|IN|INC|INDUSTRIES|INFINITI|INFO|ING|INK|INSTITUTE|INSURANCE|INSURE|INT|INTERNATIONAL|INTUIT|INVESTMENTS|IO|IPIRANGA|IQ|IR|IRISH|IS|ISMAILI|IST|ISTANBUL|IT|ITAU|ITV|JAGUAR|JAVA|JCB|JE|JEEP|JETZT|JEWELRY|JIO|JLL|JM|JMP|JNJ|JO|JOBS|JOBURG|JOT|JOY|JP|JPMORGAN|JPRS|JUEGOS|JUNIPER|KAUFEN|KDDI|KE|KERRYHOTELS|KERRYLOGISTICS|KERRYPROPERTIES|KFH|KG|KH|KI|KIA|KIM|KINDER|KINDLE|KITCHEN|KIWI|KM|KN|KOELN|KOMATSU|KOSHER|KP|KPMG|KPN|KR|KRD|KRED|KUOKGROUP|KW|KY|KYOTO|KZ|LA|LACAIXA|LAMBORGHINI|LAMER|LANCASTER|LANCIA|LAND|LANDROVER|LANXESS|LASALLE|LAT|LATINO|LATROBE|LAW|LAWYER|LB|LC|LDS|LEASE|LECLERC|LEFRAK|LEGAL|LEGO|LEXUS|LGBT|LI|LIDL|LIFE|LIFEINSURANCE|LIFESTYLE|LIGHTING|LIKE|LILLY|LIMITED|LIMO|LINCOLN|LINDE|LINK|LIPSY|LIVE|LIVING|LIXIL|LK|LLC|LLP|LOAN|LOANS|LOCKER|LOCUS|LOFT|LOL|LONDON|LOTTE|LOTTO|LOVE|LPL|LPLFINANCIAL|LR|LS|LT|LTD|LTDA|LU|LUNDBECK|LUXE|LUXURY|LV|LY|MA|MACYS|MADRID|MAIF|MAISON|MAKEUP|MAN|MANAGEMENT|MANGO|MAP|MARKET|MARKETING|MARKETS|MARRIOTT|MARSHALLS|MASERATI|MATTEL|MBA|MC|MCKINSEY|MD|ME|MED|MEDIA|MEET|MELBOURNE|MEME|MEMORIAL|MEN|MENU|MERCKMSD|MG|MH|MIAMI|MICROSOFT|MIL|MINI|MINT|MIT|MITSUBISHI|MK|ML|MLB|MLS|MM|MMA|MN|MO|MOBI|MOBILE|MODA|MOE|MOI|MOM|MONASH|MONEY|MONSTER|MORMON|MORTGAGE|MOSCOW|MOTO|MOTORCYCLES|MOV|MOVIE|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MSD|MT|MTN|MTR|MU|MUSEUM|MUTUAL|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NAB|NAGOYA|NAME|NATURA|NAVY|NBA|NC|NE|NEC|NET|NETBANK|NETFLIX|NETWORK|NEUSTAR|NEW|NEWS|NEXT|NEXTDIRECT|NEXUS|NF|NFL|NG|NGO|NHK|NI|NICO|NIKE|NIKON|NINJA|NISSAN|NISSAY|NL|NO|NOKIA|NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL|NORTON|NOW|NOWRUZ|NOWTV|NP|NR|NRA|NRW|NTT|NU|NYC|NZ|OBI|OBSERVER|OFF|OFFICE|OKINAWA|OLAYAN|OLAYANGROUP|OLDNAVY|OLLO|OM|OMEGA|ONE|ONG|ONL|ONLINE|OOO|OPEN|ORACLE|ORANGE|ORG|ORGANIC|ORIGINS|OSAKA|OTSUKA|OTT|OVH|PA|PAGE|PANASONIC|PARIS|PARS|PARTNERS|PARTS|PARTY|PASSAGENS|PAY|PCCW|PE|PET|PF|PFIZER|PG|PH|PHARMACY|PHD|PHILIPS|PHONE|PHOTO|PHOTOGRAPHY|PHOTOS|PHYSIO|PICS|PICTET|PICTURES|PID|PIN|PING|PINK|PIONEER|PIZZA|PK|PL|PLACE|PLAY|PLAYSTATION|PLUMBING|PLUS|PM|PN|PNC|POHL|POKER|POLITIE|PORN|POST|PR|PRAMERICA|PRAXI|PRESS|PRIME|PRO|PROD|PRODUCTIONS|PROF|PROGRESSIVE|PROMO|PROPERTIES|PROPERTY|PROTECTION|PRU|PRUDENTIAL|PS|PT|PUB|PW|PWC|PY|QA|QPON|QUEBEC|QUEST|QVC|RACING|RADIO|RAID|RE|READ|REALESTATE|REALTOR|REALTY|RECIPES|RED|REDSTONE|REDUMBRELLA|REHAB|REISE|REISEN|REIT|RELIANCE|REN|RENT|RENTALS|REPAIR|REPORT|REPUBLICAN|REST|RESTAURANT|REVIEW|REVIEWS|REXROTH|RICH|RICHARDLI|RICOH|RIL|RIO|RIP|RMIT|RO|ROCHER|ROCKS|RODEO|ROGERS|ROOM|RS|RSVP|RU|RUGBY|RUHR|RUN|RW|RWE|RYUKYU|SA|SAARLAND|SAFE|SAFETY|SAKURA|SALE|SALON|SAMSCLUB|SAMSUNG|SANDVIK|SANDVIKCOROMANT|SANOFI|SAP|SARL|SAS|SAVE|SAXO|SB|SBI|SBS|SC|SCA|SCB|SCHAEFFLER|SCHMIDT|SCHOLARSHIPS|SCHOOL|SCHULE|SCHWARZ|SCIENCE|SCJOHNSON|SCOT|SD|SE|SEARCH|SEAT|SECURE|SECURITY|SEEK|SELECT|SENER|SERVICES|SES|SEVEN|SEW|SEX|SEXY|SFR|SG|SH|SHANGRILA|SHARP|SHAW|SHELL|SHIA|SHIKSHA|SHOES|SHOP|SHOPPING|SHOUJI|SHOW|SHOWTIME|SI|SILK|SINA|SINGLES|SITE|SJ|SK|SKI|SKIN|SKY|SKYPE|SL|SLING|SM|SMART|SMILE|SN|SNCF|SO|SOCCER|SOCIAL|SOFTBANK|SOFTWARE|SOHU|SOLAR|SOLUTIONS|SONG|SONY|SOY|SPA|SPACE|SPORT|SPOT|SR|SRL|SS|ST|STADA|STAPLES|STAR|STATEBANK|STATEFARM|STC|STCGROUP|STOCKHOLM|STORAGE|STORE|STREAM|STUDIO|STUDY|STYLE|SU|SUCKS|SUPPLIES|SUPPLY|SUPPORT|SURF|SURGERY|SUZUKI|SV|SWATCH|SWIFTCOVER|SWISS|SX|SY|SYDNEY|SYSTEMS|SZ|TAB|TAIPEI|TALK|TAOBAO|TARGET|TATAMOTORS|TATAR|TATTOO|TAX|TAXI|TC|TCI|TD|TDK|TEAM|TECH|TECHNOLOGY|TEL|TEMASEK|TENNIS|TEVA|TF|TG|TH|THD|THEATER|THEATRE|TIAA|TICKETS|TIENDA|TIFFANY|TIPS|TIRES|TIROL|TJ|TJMAXX|TJX|TK|TKMAXX|TL|TM|TMALL|TN|TO|TODAY|TOKYO|TOOLS|TOP|TORAY|TOSHIBA|TOTAL|TOURS|TOWN|TOYOTA|TOYS|TR|TRADE|TRADING|TRAINING|TRAVEL|TRAVELCHANNEL|TRAVELERS|TRAVELERSINSURANCE|TRUST|TRV|TT|TUBE|TUI|TUNES|TUSHU|TV|TVS|TW|TZ|UA|UBANK|UBS|UG|UK|UNICOM|UNIVERSITY|UNO|UOL|UPS|US|UY|UZ|VA|VACATIONS|VANA|VANGUARD|VC|VE|VEGAS|VENTURES|VERISIGN|VERSICHERUNG|VET|VG|VI|VIAJES|VIDEO|VIG|VIKING|VILLAS|VIN|VIP|VIRGIN|VISA|VISION|VIVA|VIVO|VLAANDEREN|VN|VODKA|VOLKSWAGEN|VOLVO|VOTE|VOTING|VOTO|VOYAGE|VU|VUELOS|WALES|WALMART|WALTER|WANG|WANGGOU|WATCH|WATCHES|WEATHER|WEATHERCHANNEL|WEBCAM|WEBER|WEBSITE|WED|WEDDING|WEIBO|WEIR|WF|WHOSWHO|WIEN|WIKI|WILLIAMHILL|WIN|WINDOWS|WINE|WINNERS|WME|WOLTERSKLUWER|WOODSIDE|WORK|WORKS|WORLD|WOW|WS|WTC|WTF|XBOX|XEROX|XFINITY|XIHUAN|XIN|XXX|XYZ|YACHTS|YAHOO|YAMAXUN|YANDEX|YE|YODOBASHI|YOGA|YOKOHAMA|YOU|YOUTUBE|YT|YUN|ZA|ZAPPOS|ZARA|ZERO|ZIP|ZM|ZONE|ZUERICH|ZW)$
```